# Adding new function in existing class

Tags: magento2, overrides, override-block

I want to add a new function in class `Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList` so, that I can use that function in template file of this block.

Can I add a new function without using preferences? If yes, how? And then how can I use the new function in phtml file?

Suppose, I have to add the function `isNew()` in class `Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList` and then I need to call this function in override template `app/design/frontend/Mythem/newtheme/Magento_CatalogWidget/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml` like `$block->isNew()`

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code:**
The content of `di.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" type="MY_NAMESPACE\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" />
</config>
```

The content of `ProductsList.php` is:

```
<?php

namespace MY_NAMESPACE\CatalogWidget\Block\Product;

class ProductsList extends \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList
{
    public function isNew()
    {
        die('Hello World !');
    }
}

?>
```